# How to run Windows compiled for PowerPC on Modern PowerPC machines without instruction set enumeration?

Tags: virtual-machine, powerpc, windows-nt-4, winapi

Windows® NT supported more architectures in the past, but similar to Apple with their Mac, Windows® for PowerPC required an [ARC BIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_RISC_Computing) in order to be booted *(please note this doesn’t only concern this architecture)*.

Virtualization answers like [this one](http://gunkies.org/wiki/Installing_Windows_NT_4.0_on_Qemu(MIPS)) are OK. The aim is to still be able to test the target with [this compiler](https://github.com/open-watcom/).

So how to boot windows NT 4.0 on a recent PowerPC compatible *(by compatible, I mean with ISA; ram modules; graphics cards…)* hardware ?

And please don’t close this question because of hardware difference. Everyting is backward compatible like [with the x86 version](http://www.betaarchive.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=33418); it just can’t take advantages of new features *(and in fact I’m still a Win9x user)*.

Comment: **Downvotes ? Why ?**.If you have source code written for the winapi, then using one of those outdated versions is the best way to run such programs on that hardware.

Answer (score 4):

This is impossible.

Modern PowerPC computers use completely different hardware interfaces and a different bootloader. There is a collection of peripherals that Windows NT expects to be on every system, and if it doesn't support them it won't boot. In simple terms there aren't drivers.

Comment: So what about things that don’t require ᴄᴘᴜ instruction emulation ? *(I’m thinking to what is possible with [modern ᴍɪᴘꜱ](http://gunkies.org/wiki/Installing_Windows_NT_4.0_on_Qemu(MIPS)))*. Otherwise please note main blocking differences like disk with 4096 sector size is still not a huge problem. ᴀʀᴄ ʙɪᴏꜱ is the only problem here.

Comment: @user2284570 This isn't about emulation. The OP wanted to know if he could install it on a physical machine, you can't because modern machines interface with hardware differently.

Comment: I’m the ᴏᴘ. My only concern is to avoid translating ᴄᴘᴜ instructions into those of an another architecture because of the high processing cost. I even wrote “Virtualization answers like [this one](http://gunkies.org/wiki/Installing_Windows_NT_4.0_on_Qemu(MIPS) "qemu ᴡindows‑ɴᴛ ᴍɪᴘꜱ") are OK. The aim is for still be able to test the target with [this compiler](https://github.com/open-watcom/).”

Comment: @user2284570 thats great but thats not the question you asked.

Comment: No, the arc bios requirement was present in the question since the beginning.